Repeating a range of numbers by their corresponding frequency value

As you will see in the image, what I am trying to do is repeat a data value by the number of times mentioned in the frequency column and have it appear in the same row. I need a dynamic formula as the number of rows will change frequently.
My ultimate goal is to have everything in one column, so a solution that compresses everything into one column works as well.
So far I've tried SEQUENCE, but giving a range as input doesn't work.
I tried BYROW but that returns only one column, so that doesn't work either.

You may try =EXPAND(A2,1,B2,A2).
